# get_filename_component unknown component DIRECTORY

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

## Problem description

I am having a problem with the following `CmakeList.txt` file.

- **Source code directory:** `/home/hani/entitylinking`
- **Header files :** `/entitylinking/3rdparty/include/entlk`
- **Target installation directory :** `/home/hani/ENTLK_DIST`

I added the `message(STATUS "_file:" ${_file} )` as proposed in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900252/cmake-get-filename-component-unknown-component-directory) to check where the files are located. And I don't get what is the error.

I am actually also working on a server. not on my machine.

---

## CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE _files RELATIVE ${Entlk_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/include/ *.h)
# TODO if needed, let append a list of *.hpp files. A solution may be to replace by
# file(GLOB_RECURSE _files RELATIVE ${Entlk_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/include/ *.h??)

foreach (_file ${_files})
  # get the real file instead of the symbolic link
  message(STATUS "_file:" ${_file} )

  get_filename_component(_resolvedFile "${_file}" REALPATH)

  # get the relative path to install
  get_filename_component(dir "${_file}" DIRECTORY)

  message(STATUS "_resolvedFile:" ${_resolvedFile} )

  install(FILES ${_resolvedFile} DESTINATION include/${dir})
endforeach()
```

---

## Messages

The messages that I am getting are the following

```
-- _resolvedFile:/home/hani/entitylinking/3rdparty/sqlite3/sqlite_modern_cpp/utility/function_traits.h
-- _file:entlk/3rdparty/simstring/memory_mapped_file.h
CMake Error at 3rdparty/include/CMakeLists.txt:12 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component unknown component DIRECTORY


-- _resolvedFile:/home/hani/entitylinking/3rdparty/include/entlk/3rdparty/simstring/memory_mapped_file.h
-- _file:entlk/3rdparty/simstring/measure.h
CMake Error at 3rdparty/include/CMakeLists.txt:12 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component unknown component DIRECTORY
```

Comment: I assume there should be no space in the first line in `/ *.h` Also I would put quotation marks around the whole argument

Comment: @usr1234567 when I removed the space It gave me the following error: `CMake Error at 3rdparty/include/CMakeLists.txt:1 (file):
  file GLOB requires a glob expression after the directory` . the same goes with the quotation marks. I added a quotation mark around `"${Entlk_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/include/*.h"`

Comment: Still, it would be the right way. What's your CMake version? If you CMake is older then 2.8.11, DIRECTORY is unknown. Then you should use PATH. Or better update your CMake…

Comment: Oh wait wait when I did the following `"${Entlk_SOURCE_DIR}"/3rdparty/include/*.h` It worked. What exactly was the problem. Your comments answered my question.  You can add it as an answer if u wish?.But Please tell me why is it wrong?

Comment: @HaniGoc The first line of your main CMakeLists.txt should be something like `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)`